# How to add a custom library (e.g. glew) to mingw-w64?

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64, glew

I'm using windows and my goal is to add the glew library (http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html) to mingw. I have downloaded mingw-w64 via GitHub (https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases/tag/20210423). It comes with a "bin", "lib" and "include" folder. Within the "bin" folder I do "make" to execute my project's makefile which inlcudes the line

```
LDLIBS=-lm -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw
```

I have copied "glew32.lib" to "mingw/lib", "GL/glew.h" and "GL/wglew.h" to "mingw/include/GL" and "bin/glew32.dll" to "mingw/bin".

In my source code i have included the header file with

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

When i do "make" i get an error on that line:

```
GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
```

How do you add custom libraries like glew to mingw?

Comment: You need to specify the path to the directory containing `GL/glew.h` using the `-I` flag (`-Iyour/path/here`).

Comment: The next problem you're going to face is that `.lib` static libraries are usually intended for MSVC. You either need to find GLEW compiled for MinGW, or compile it yourself.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is -I a gcc flag? I could not find it here http://www.spec.org/cpu2017/flags/gcc.2017-11-20.html#user_L-libpath. I've only found the -L flag.

Regarding your second comment: ...thanks for the hint!

Comment: Look in the manual instead of some random site: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a library use the `-I` compiler flag to tell the compiler where to find the include files (in your case the path containing the `GL` folder) and the `-L` linker flag to tell the linker where to find the libraries.

To link with the library use the `-l` flag. The library itself is a a `lib*.a` file (or `lib*.dll.a` for shared libraries). For the `-l` flag the library is specified without prefix and suffix, so if your library is called `libglew.a` the flag will be `-lglew`.

It is also possible to specified the full path to the `lib*.a` file instead of `-L` and `-l` flags, and with MinGW, if you have the `.dll` file you can even try to specify the path of the `.dll` file and the linker will know what to do.